# Which preferences do I need, to get angular2 worked with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and want to build an angular2 project. Which preferences do I have to have?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Comment: This is for Visual Studio 2015 and not for 2013